# Why are the emails still visible after .Disconnect() method is called in POP3?

Tags: c#, pop3, disconnect

Could somebody help me to find out what's happening?

My code connects to email>reads the body>parses the data> saves them to database> delete the email.
It does all that fine. I checked by retrieving their emailIds. 
The issue here is that the emails  are still visible in the Gmail Inbox, although, Disconnect method was supposed to delete them physically from server. Why are they still in the inbox? Is that normal? Does it take some time to delete the emails from the inbox? Or will it always be visible in inbox? or Does deleting emails physically from server not mean that they are deleted from the inbox?

Could some body with experience with POP3 in c# help me with this issue?

Thank you,

Comment: What POP3 client library are you using?

Comment: OpenPop.dll from sourceforge.net

Answer (score 2):

Gmail has a setting that allows you to delete messages from POP. See the following: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13290

Comment: i will run this by my mentor and see what he says. If this works, it would be great...all that i did would finally pay-off...because this is the only spot that i am stuck at. thanks

Comment: my supervisor decided to use imap instead of POP3. we faced quite a few situations while using POP3.
While using imap, i did have to go to gmail>>settings>>POP3/Imap>> Enable IMAP, before using accessing gmail account through .net.